# Storing map in properties file

Tags: java, properties, dictionary, hashmap, config

I know that I can build a Map as below.

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String,String> WordMap = 
ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
.put("blah", "blahblah").put("blabla", "blahblahblah").build()
```

I'd like to store the values of my map in a config file.
I'm already storing the values for a different hashset in the config file by doing
`values=value1,value2,value3` and then
`new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty(values).split(",")))`

I'd like to do something similar for my map. 
Any tips?
I'm using `java.util.Properties`

Comment: I guess you don't want to add the map by putting each key/value pair from your map in `Properties` (via `properties.putAll(WordMap)`) - instead you try to put the whole map as a single value into the properties?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you've indicated you don't want to use JSON, you could store the map as a single property like this:

```
map=key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3
```

Use [Guava's Splitter and Joiner](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) to simplify reading and writing the map:

```
String formatMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    return Joiner.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(map);
}

Map<String, String> parseMap(String formattedMap) {
    return Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(formattedMap);
}
```

This will work so long as the keys and values do not contain "," or "=" characters.

Comment: thanks! so i could just get the property, call parseMap and set it equal to my map

Comment: would there be an efficient way to do the second statement with a reverse order? if i want a value -> key map as well and don't want to go through the entire thing and recreate a new one or store a second configuration in the properties file

Comment: @Lemonio look at Guava's BiMap: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 2):

Format the contents of the Map as a String. Use a standard format like JSON. With the [json-smart](http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/) library this would look something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putAll(WordMap);
String serializedMap = json.toString();
prop.setProperty("wordMap", serializedMap);
```

To parse the map:

```
String serializedMap = prop.getProperty("wordMap");
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(serializedMap);
Map<String, String> wordMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : json.entrySet()) {
    wordMap.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! does the map have to be created with that code? is properties more than just a text file? because the idea was people would be able to configure the contents of the map within the text file, if they need to run code to do it there's no point in including it as they might as well change the put statements in the code

Comment: The idea behind this answer was that if you want to store the word map in a single property, you'll need to format it as a string. JSON is a standard format with good library support, but since you intend for end-users to edit the properties file JSON probably isn't the best choice. Just use whatever format you think will be simplest for your users, and write custom code to format and parse it. map=key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value4 would work fine, as long as your keys and values can never contain "=" or "," characters.

Comment: After posting this answer, Jackson has become my library of choice for JSON [de]serialization and data binding.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Properties internally uses hashtable for storing the key value pairs mentioned in the properties file. You can make full use of it for your purpose.

Comment: You may want to also change  that it doesn't _use internally_. I understand that as it has an instance variable. It actually `extends Hashtable`. It may confuse others.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot public
class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>

Comment: i can? how? do i just write map=(key,value),(key,value) etc... ?